# Best practices for improving Full Text Search in Neo4j, Apollo Server and Graphql

Tags: neo4j, graphql, lucene, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am currently trying to build a search application on top of SNOMED CT international FULL RF 2 Release. The database is quite huge and I had decided to move on with a full text search index for optimal results. So there are primarily 3 types of nodes in a SNOMED CT database :

ObjectConcept
Descriptions
Role Group
There are multiple relationships between the nodes but I'm focussing on that later.
Currently I'm focussing on searching for ObjectConcept Nodes by a String property value called FSN which stands for fully specified name. For this I tried two things :
Create text indexes on FSN :   After using this with MATCH queries the results were rather slow even when I was using the CONTAINS predicate and limiting return value to 15.
Create Full Text Indexes:   According to the docs, the FT indexes are powered by Apache Lucene. I created this for FSN. After using the FT Indexes and using AND clauses in the search term, for example :

> Search Term : head pain
> Query Term: head AND pain

I observe quite impressive benefits in query time using the profiler in neo4j browser(around from 43ms to 10ms for some queries) however once I start querying the db using the apollo server, query times go as high as 2s - 3s. Sometimes upto 8-10s.
The query is as follows, implemented by a custom resolver in neo4j/graphql and apollo-server:

```
` const session = context.driver.session()
 let words = args.name.split(" ");
 let compoundQuery = "";
 if (words.length === 1) compoundQuery = words[0];
 else compoundQuery = words.join(" AND ");
 console.log(compoundQuery)
 compoundQuery+= AND (${args.type})
 return session
    .run(
   
    `CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('searchIndex',$name) YIELD node, score
    RETURN node
    LIMIT 10
    `,
    { name: compoundQuery }
    )
  .then((res) => {
  session.close()
  return res.records.map((record) => {
  return record.get('node').properties
   })
  })
} `
```

I have the following questions:

Am I utilising FT indexes as much as I can or am I missing important optimisations out?
I was trying to implement elasticsearch with neo4j but I read elasticsearch and the FT indexes are both powered by lucene. So am I likely to gain improvements from using elasticsearch? If so? how should I go about it considering that I am using neo4j aura db and my graphql server is on ec2. I am confused as to how to use elasticsearch overall with the GRANDStack.     
Any help would be appreciated.
Any other Suggestions for optimising search would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us how you are creating the index? Are you using the latest v 4.4.x with its enhanced full text index? It's discussed on this YouTube starting at ~18:15. Have you looked at Campbell's work: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jbi.2015.08.016

Comment: I have used the documentation at https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/ for creating the full text search indexes. Could you mention which youtube video you are talking about? 
Yes I have been through Campbell's work.